# CSS overwriting commands

Tags: html, css

I would like to put a box in my page body but exclude the two elements in the upper area.

I wrote the code for the elements, but it seems that it have been ignored:

EDIT: I added the HTML. I cannot create other div's, so I don't know how to specify that the two elements must be excluded from the code written in the body's css.

```css
body {
 background-image: url("https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/background.png");
 margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   font-size: 8pt;
   font-family: "Tahoma";
   width: 800px;
   border: 4px solid red;
}

#banner {
 text-align: center;
 background-image: url("https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/bannerbg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 50px;
    
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-style: bold;
 font-family: "Verdana";
 font-size: 24pt;
 text-shadow: 3px 3px #999999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <head>
  <title>TMNT - Rancid Tomatoes</title>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link href="movie.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="banner">
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/banner.png" alt="Rancid Tomatoes">
  </div>

  <h1>TMNT (2007)</h1>
  
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/overview.png" alt="general overview">
  </div>

  <dl>
   <dt>STARRING</dt>
   <dd>Patrick Stewart <br> Mako <br> Sarah Michelle Gellar <br> Kevin Smith</dd>

   <dt>DIRECTOR</dt>
   <dd>Kevin Munroe</dd>

   <dt>RATING</dt>
   <dd>PG</dd>

   <dt>THEATRICAL RELEASE</dt>
   <dd>Mar 23, 2007</dd>

   <dt>MOVIE SYNOPSIS</dt>
   <dd>After the defeat of their old arch nemesis, The Shredder, the Turtles have grown apart as a family.</dd>

   <dt>MPAA RATING</dt>
   <dd>PG, for animated action violence, some scary cartoon images and mild language</dd>

   <dt>RELEASE COMPANY</dt>
   <dd>Warner Bros.</dd>

   <dt>RUNTIME</dt>
   <dd>90 mins</dd>

   <dt>GENRE</dt>
   <dd>Action/Adventure, Comedies, Childrens, Martial Arts, Superheroes, Ninjas, Animated Characters</dd>

   <dt>BOX OFFICE</dt>
   <dd>$54,132,596</dd>

   <dt>LINKS</dt>
   <dd>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="http://www.ninjaturtles.com/">The Official TMNT Site</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/teenage_mutant_ninja_turtles/">RT Review</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/">RT Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="http://www.cs.washington.edu/190m/">CSE 190 M</a></li>
    </ul>
   </dd>
  </dl>

  <div>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rottenbig.png" alt="Rotten">
   33%
  </div>
  
  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
   <q>Ditching the cheeky, self-aware wink that helped to excuse the concept's inherent corniness, the movie attempts to look polished and 'cool,' but the been-there animation can't compete with the then-cutting-edge puppetry of the 1990 live-action movie.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic">
   Peter Debruge <br>
   Variety
  </p>

  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh">
   <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic">
   Todd Gilchrist <br>
   IGN Movies
  </p>

  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
   <q>It stinks!</q>
  </p>
  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic">
   Jay Sherman (unemployed)
  </p>

  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
   <q>The rubber suits are gone and they've been redone with fancy computer technology, but that hasn't stopped them from becoming dull.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic">
   Joshua Tyler <br>
   CinemaBlend.com
  </p>

  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
   <q>YOUR REVIEW HERE</q>
  </p>
  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic">
   NAME <br>
   PUBLICATION
  </p>

  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
   <q>The turtles themselves may look prettier, but are no smarter; torn irreparably from their countercultural roots, our superheroes on the half shell have been firmly co-opted by the industry their creators once sought to spoof.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic">
   Jeannette Catsoulis <br>
   New York Times
  </p>

  <p class="rotten">
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
   <q>Impersonally animated and arbitrarily plotted, the story appears to have been made up as the filmmakers went along.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic">
   Ed Gonzalez <br>
   Slant Magazine
  </p>

  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh">
   <q>The striking use of image and motion allows each sequence to leave an impression. It's an accomplished restart to this franchise.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic">
   Mark Palermo <br>
   Coast (Halifax, Nova Scotia)
  </p>

  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
   <q>The script feels like it was computer generated. This mechanical presentation lacks the cheesy charm of the three live action films.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic">
   Steve Rhodes <br>
   Internet Reviews
  </p>

  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
   <q>YOUR REVIEW HERE</q>
  </p>
  <p>
   <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic">
   NAME <br>
   PUBLICATION
  </p>

  <p>(1-10) of 88</p>

  <div>
   <a href="ttp://validator.w3.org/check/referer"><img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/w3c-xhtml.png" alt="Validate HTML">></a> <br>
   <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer"><img src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss" alt="Valid CSS!"></a>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is how the page should be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcZZi.png)

Comment: Your code does not demostrate the issue. Did you omit the HTML?

Comment: what is the actual error? getting a bit lost in this post ...

Comment: If you don't show your HTML noone will be able to help you.

Comment: You can rewrite CSS rules, but the behaviour depends quite a lot on the rendering engine (there can be differences in Firefox, Chrome, Edge, Opera, etc.)

Comment: I added the HTML

Comment: You now have two separate code snippets. One has CSS with no HTML and the other has HTML with no CSS. Edit them together into a single [mcve].

Comment: You should make it clearer what behaviour you want. What do you want to exclude from what?

Comment: I would like to exclude the banner and the title

Comment: So set `display: none` for `#banner` and the following `h1` …?

Comment: Removing the banner and the title from the HTML is not a good idea because... ?

Comment: In this case the elements get deleted. I would like to override the rules of the body only for the banner and the h1

Comment: I cannot delete that elements. They must be in the body but not in the box model that I wanna create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have limited the width of the `body` and this is *not recommended*. Instead wrap everything except the elements you want excluded in a *separate* container div and limit the width of *that*.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/background.png");
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-family: "Tahoma";
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

#banner {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/bannerbg.png");
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  height: 50px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-style: bold;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 24pt;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px #999999;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/banner.png" alt="Rancid Tomatoes">
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>TMNT (2007)</h1>

  <div>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/overview.png" alt="general overview">
  </div>

  <dl>
    <dt>STARRING</dt>
    <dd>Patrick Stewart <br> Mako <br> Sarah Michelle Gellar <br> Kevin Smith</dd>

    <dt>DIRECTOR</dt>
    <dd>Kevin Munroe</dd>

    <dt>RATING</dt>
    <dd>PG</dd>

    <dt>THEATRICAL RELEASE</dt>
    <dd>Mar 23, 2007</dd>

    <dt>MOVIE SYNOPSIS</dt>
    <dd>After the defeat of their old arch nemesis, The Shredder, the Turtles have grown apart as a family.</dd>

    <dt>MPAA RATING</dt>
    <dd>PG, for animated action violence, some scary cartoon images and mild language</dd>

    <dt>RELEASE COMPANY</dt>
    <dd>Warner Bros.</dd>

    <dt>RUNTIME</dt>
    <dd>90 mins</dd>

    <dt>GENRE</dt>
    <dd>Action/Adventure, Comedies, Childrens, Martial Arts, Superheroes, Ninjas, Animated Characters</dd>

    <dt>BOX OFFICE</dt>
    <dd>$54,132,596</dd>

    <dt>LINKS</dt>
    <dd>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://www.ninjaturtles.com/">The Official TMNT Site</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/teenage_mutant_ninja_turtles/">RT Review</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.rottentomatoes.com/">RT Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.cs.washington.edu/190m/">CSE 190 M</a></li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </dl>

  <div>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rottenbig.png" alt="Rotten"> 33%
  </div>

  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
    <q>Ditching the cheeky, self-aware wink that helped to excuse the concept's inherent corniness, the movie attempts to look polished and 'cool,' but the been-there animation can't compete with the then-cutting-edge puppetry of the 1990 live-action movie.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic"> Peter Debruge <br> Variety
  </p>

  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh">
    <q>TMNT is a fun, action-filled adventure that will satisfy longtime fans and generate a legion of new ones.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic"> Todd Gilchrist <br> IGN Movies
  </p>

  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
    <q>It stinks!</q>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic"> Jay Sherman (unemployed)
  </p>

  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
    <q>The rubber suits are gone and they've been redone with fancy computer technology, but that hasn't stopped them from becoming dull.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic"> Joshua Tyler <br> CinemaBlend.com
  </p>

  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
    <q>YOUR REVIEW HERE</q>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic"> NAME <br> PUBLICATION
  </p>

  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
    <q>The turtles themselves may look prettier, but are no smarter; torn irreparably from their countercultural roots, our superheroes on the half shell have been firmly co-opted by the industry their creators once sought to spoof.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic"> Jeannette Catsoulis <br> New York Times
  </p>

  <p class="rotten">
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
    <q>Impersonally animated and arbitrarily plotted, the story appears to have been made up as the filmmakers went along.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic"> Ed Gonzalez <br> Slant Magazine
  </p>

  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/fresh.gif" alt="Fresh">
    <q>The striking use of image and motion allows each sequence to leave an impression. It's an accomplished restart to this franchise.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic"> Mark Palermo <br> Coast (Halifax, Nova Scotia)
  </p>

  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
    <q>The script feels like it was computer generated. This mechanical presentation lacks the cheesy charm of the three live action films.</q>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic"> Steve Rhodes <br> Internet Reviews
  </p>

  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/rotten.gif" alt="Rotten">
    <q>YOUR REVIEW HERE</q>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/critic.gif" alt="Critic"> NAME <br> PUBLICATION
  </p>

  <p>(1-10) of 88</p>

  <div>
    <a href="ttp://validator.w3.org/check/referer"><img src="http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse190m/11sp/homework/2/w3c-xhtml.png" alt="Validate HTML">></a> <br>
    <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer"><img src="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/images/vcss" alt="Valid CSS!"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```